# Combining two audio files in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, audio

There are 2 audio ( mp3 or wav) files. The first file has the voice of me, the second one has the voice of my friend. Each of them has **10 seconds** duration. 
I want to combine them to get **one file** that also should have  **10 seconds** duration.

What are the tools or utilities I should use to solve this issue?

UPDATE: I used lame.exe, but it **concatenated** them and  created the file of 20 seconds duration.

Comment: Use Audacity: http://audacity.sourceforge.net/download/

Comment: How do I use it? Do you have any example?

Comment: http://manual.audacityteam.org/help/manual/man/faq_editing.html#mix

Comment: You understood me wrong. I need to do it programmatically in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out NAudio tutorial: [Mixing multiple wave files together in real time](http://opensebj.blogspot.com/2009/02/naudio-tutorial-2-mixing-multiple-wave.html).

Comment: It seems it's what I want. But I didn't understand that example. How it could help me?

Answer (score 4):

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35725/C-WAV-file-class-audio-mixing-and-some-light-audio) might do the trick.

> My WAVFile class supports 8- and 16-bit audio, mono or stereo. One of
>   its special features is a method that will mix WAV audio files
>   together, so that the audio from each source WAV file will be heard
>   simultaneously.

Note: In the above paragraph, `My` refers to the author of the class, not to myself.